# Summernote Add Function when inserting table

Tags: javascript, jquery, summernote

I'm trying to apply a Resizable function in the tables when I insert them in summernote. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: what have  u tried ?

Comment: i tried to add a function when the page starts but resizable function requires a table present in the editor.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, this worked for me,

```
this.insertTable = this.wrapCommand(function (dim) {
        var dimension = dim.split('x');
        var rng = this.createRange().deleteContents();
        rng.insertNode(table.createTable(dimension[0], dimension[1], options));
        $('.note-editable table').resizable({
            handles: "n, w, e, s"
        });
        $('.note-editable td').resizable({
            handles: "e, s"
        });
    });
```